# js parsing XML from JSP, storing values

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, arrays

I'm parsing XML and would like to store the values in an easy-to-read fashion.

I am getting mapShapes and mapPoints (so x and y coordinates).  An (x,y) pair makes a point, a collection of points makes a Shape.

Here is some example XML that I would like to parse:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<mapQuery id='10918014'>
    <mapShape id='429436'>
        <mapPoint id='4259799'>
            <x>-81.61508</x>
            <y>41.52184</y>
        </mapPoint>
        <mapPoint id='4259800'>
            <x>-81.61537</x>
            <y>41.52181</y>
        </mapPoint>
        <mapPoint id='4259801'>
            <x>-81.61538</x>
            <y>41.522198</y>
        </mapPoint>
        <mapPoint id='4259802'>
            <x>-81.61516</x>
            <y>41.52222</y>
        </mapPoint>
        <mapPoint id='4259803'>
            <x>-81.61508</x>
            <y>41.52184</y>
        </mapPoint>
    </mapShape>
</mapQuery>
```

I would like to end up with an array like

```
shapes[0].point[0].x[0] = first x point
shapes[0].point[0].y[0] = first y point
```

(this example XML only has one shape present, but there could be several.)

Thanks in advance for the help with an easy question =)

Here's some skeleton code:

```
shapeXmlHandler : function(xml){

    $(xml).find("mapShape").each(function(){
        $(this).find("mapPoint").each(function() {
            console.log('mapPoint: '+$(this).attr('id'));
            console.log('x :'+$(this).find("x").text());
            console.log('y :'+$(this).find("y").text());
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: What's the problem you're having? Looks good so far (except that I think you actually want `shapes[0].point[0].x = first x point` etc.)

Comment: good call.  I'm not really sure how to accomplish the goal, but I'm pretty close.  I don't really know what the best approach is for putting the xml data into an array while parsing over it, so I was asking for suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`Array.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

```
shapeXmlHandler : function(xml)
{
    var shapes = [];

    $(xml).find('mapShape').each(function()
    {
        var shape = [];

        $(this).find('mapPoint').each(function()
        {
            var $p = $(this),
                point = 
                {
                    x: $p.find('x').text(),
                    y: $p.find('y').text()
                };

            shape.push(point);
        });

        shapes.push(shape);
    });

    console.log(shapes);
}
```

This should log something like

```
[
    [
        {x: -81.61508, y: 41.52184},
        {x: -81.61537, y: 41.52181},
        ...
    ]
]
```

---

This can be done a bit slicker using [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map) instead of `.each()`:

```
shapeXmlHandler : function(xml)
{
    var shapes = $(xml).find('mapShape').map(function()
    {
        return $(this).find('mapPoint').map(function()
        {
            var $p = $(this);
            return {
                x: $p.find('x').text(),
                y: $p.find('y').text()
            };
        }).get();
    }).get();

    console.log(shapes);
}
```

---

And if there's any chance of working with JSON instead of XML, you don't need any custom parsing code at all! Just use [`$.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your thorough answer.  Would give you two upvotes if I could =)

Comment: Thanks, no worries. Which approach did you end up using?

Comment: Is the .get() necessary for .map()?  I don't get any console output unless I leave the .get() off, but it shows a lot more stuff than just the array (like all sorts of jQuery methods).  I am using the first approach probably -- it's still uncertain if I even need to hold onto the input for too long so I might just pass it as I process it

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the output. In most cases you'll want to use `.get()` so you're working with a simple vanilla JavaScript array rather than a jQuery object. The `.get()` call after `.map()` is idiomatic jQuery.

Comment: That said it's possible that nested `.map()` calls like that should actually omit the inner `.get()` call. I haven't played around with it to find out for myself.

Comment: Right on.  Actually, I removed the secondary "shape" array and simply used shapes.push(point)... Having both returned a doubly nested array [ [ Object { x="...", y="..." }, Object { x="...", y="..." }, etc ] ].  It's easier for me to refer to it as shapes[0].x now as opposed to shapes[0][0], shapes[0][1] etc, since shapes[1] is never defined so the index is extraneous in this context for me